# Can logrotate create missing files?

Tags: shell, cron, logrotate

I was looking through the logrotate directives, and it seems that `create` will only create a new log file after rotation. I just get an error if the log file is missing. Is there a way to trigger creation of the log file with the correct permission, ownership and group if the log file does not exist? It doesn't have to be in logrotate, but that'd be preferred.

Comment: Where do you have error?  No files - no rotate. Chech doc for your service.

Comment: Somehow the log file got deleted, but I didn't no until much later. I'd like for the file to be recreated once logrotate detects the missing file.

Comment: If you need for just once ```touch /var/log/LOGFILE.log``` logrotate has some different purpose than to create files.

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for something that would automatically trigger once logrotate sees that the log file is missing. But yeah, I agree with your conclusion of logrotate. I was just asking just in case I was wrong and was missing something.